# Getting run-time error 'image uri must be of the content scheme type' in Android Code

Tags: android, react-native

I am exporting a module from Android to use in the React-Native app.
I want to set a wallpaper from a React-Native app.

So, I have written a below code in the exported module in Android.

```
public void setNewWallpaperFromUrl(String path) {
    context = getReactApplicationContext();
    WallpaperManager wpm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context);
    try {
        //InputStream ins = new URL(path).openStream();
        //path="https://res.cloudinary.com/dwgtksajb/image/upload/v1536237557/wallpaper/Nature/1536237557101_readtrip.jfif.jpg"
        wpm.getCropAndSetWallpaperIntent(Uri.parse(path));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw  ex;
    }
}
```

It compiles successfully. But on run-time I am getting an error: 'image URI must be of the content scheme type'

Any quick help is really appreciated.

Comment: I got the answer from Android official docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from Android official docs.
getCropAndSetWallpaperIntent(Uri uri) method only excepts 'Content' scheme uri.

Please visit [enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html#getCropAndSetWallpaperIntent(android.net.Uri))

for more informations.